# flutter_carousel_slider issue using jumpToPage instance method

Tags: flutter

I am doing a gallery with pop up which mean when users click a photo they will view the photo in full screen, and it is scrollable, the problem is when I close the pop up I need it to synchronise with the original gallery, which I tried to implement the jumpToPage() instance method. I am looking for a way to use it since declaring an external variable for the widget will not allow me to use the ValueNotifier and build context. I am a newbie and will greatly appreciate your feedback.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';

final List<String> imgList = [
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/704150/pexels-photo-704150.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1649771/pexels-photo-1649771.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
  'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1919338/pexels-photo-1919338.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/800',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600'
];

List<T> map<T>(List list, Function handler) {
  List<T> result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    result.add(handler(i, list[i]));
  }

  return result;
}

class ProductCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductCarouselState createState() => _ProductCarouselState();
}

class _ProductCarouselState extends State<ProductCarousel> {
  ValueNotifier<int> current = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  final ValueNotifier<bool> gotFullScreen = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      new CarouselSlider(
        initialPage: 0,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.8,
        enableInfiniteScroll: false,
        autoPlay: false,
        viewportFraction: 1.0,
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        enlargeCenterPage: false,
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          if (gotFullScreen.value == false) {
            gotFullScreen.value = true;
          } else {
            current.value = index;
          }
        },
        items: map<Widget>(
          imgList,
          (index, i) {
            return Container(
              child: ClipRect(
                  child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                heightFactor: 5.0,
                widthFactor: 1.0,
                child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: Image.network(i, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
                          opaque: false,
                          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) =>
                              galleryDialog()));
                      setState(() {
                        gotFullScreen.value = true;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0.0,
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              )),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      ),
      ValueListenableBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget child) {
          return Positioned(
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.95,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: map<Widget>(imgList, (index, url) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 8.0,
                    height: 8.0,
                    margin:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: current.value == index
                            ? Colors.black
                            : Colors.grey),
                  );
                }),
              ));
        },
        valueListenable: current,
      ),
    ]);
  }

  //Fullscreen gallery

  Widget galleryDialog() {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
          ],
          leading: new Container(),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Stack(children: [
          ValueListenableBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget child) {
              return CarouselSlider(
                items: map<Widget>(
                  imgList,
                  (index, i) {
                    return Container(
                      child: ClipRect(
                          child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        heightFactor: 10.0,
                        widthFactor: 1.0,
                        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                          PhotoView(
                            imageProvider: NetworkImage(i),
                            minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 1.0,
                            maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 3.0,
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 0.0,
                            left: 0.0,
                            right: 0.0,
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                              ),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 0, horizontal: 0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      )),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
                initialPage: gotFullScreen.value ? current.value : 0,
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                autoPlay: false,
                viewportFraction: 1.0,
                aspectRatio: 0.65,
                enlargeCenterPage: false,
                onPageChanged: (index) {
                  if (gotFullScreen.value == true && index == 1) {
                    current.value += 1;
                    setState(() {
                      gotFullScreen.value = false;
                    });
                  } else if (gotFullScreen.value == true && index != 1) {
                    current.value -= 1;
                    setState(() {
                      gotFullScreen.value = false;
                    });
                  } else if (gotFullScreen.value == false) {
                    current.value = index;
                  }
                },
              );
            },
            valueListenable: current,
          ),
          ValueListenableBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget child) {
              return Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2,
                  left: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: map<Widget>(imgList, (index, url) {
                      return Container(
                        width: 8.0,
                        height: 8.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            color: current.value == index
                                ? Colors.white
                                : Colors.brown),
                      );
                    }),
                  ));
            },
            valueListenable: current,
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

I expect a synchronisation between the original gallery and the fullscreen view. Please view the link below for a clearer picture

[The carousel for my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLVDE.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the same logic used in example for buttonControlledCarousel.

Check the role example in link bellow:
https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

The logic is something like this:

```
Widget buttonDemo() {
// pre-assign the CarouselSlider Widget
  final basicSlider = CarouselSlider(
    items: child,
    autoPlay: false,
    enlargeCenterPage: true,
    viewportFraction: 0.9,
    aspectRatio: 2.0,
    initialPage: 2,
  );
  return Column(children: [
    basicSlider,
    Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
      Flexible(
        child: RaisedButton(
          // use variable to reference method
          onPressed: () => basicSlider.jumpToPage(yourPageNumberToJump),
          child: Text('←'),
        ),
      ),
```